# Salvar entidades com relacionamento um para muitos utilizando WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Estou começando um projeto em WebApi e me deparei com uma situação que não soube como definir a minha classe de `Controller`. Tenho a seguinte estrutura

```
public class Artigo {
    public int ArtigoId { get; set; }
    public int AutorId { get; set; }
    ...
    public IQueryable<ConteudoArtigo> ConteudosArtigo  { get; set; }
}

public class ConteudoArtigo {
    public int ConteudoArtigoId { get; set; }
    public int ArtigoId  { get; set; }
    public int IdiomaId { get; set; }
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    public string Texto { get; set; }
}
```

A minha dúvida é se eu devo utilizar duas chamadas `POST` para a `API` para salvar cada conteúdo individualmente, com perigo de ocorrer algum problema e ter a chance do conteúdo filho não ser salvo ou utilizar uma única chamada para o `Controller` pai e o mesmo salvar o conteúdo do registro filho?

Seguem detalhes da modelagem

- Inicialmente é bom ressaltar que simplifiquei as entidades para não encher de código.
- Ao criar um artigo, você vai cria-lo em um idioma e este mesmo artigo pode ser traduzido em vários idiomas. Para cada idioma ira existir um registro de conteúdo.
- A ideia de ter o artigo como entidade pai foi que os comentários e avaliações serão do artigo, independente do idioma que ele esteja

Comment: Sabe ta estranho esse modelo que você passou, sinceridade não entendi !!!

Comment: @FCCDias Inicialmente é bom ressaltar que simplifiquei as entidades para não encher de código. Ao criar um artigo, você vai cria-lo em um idioma e este mesmo artigo pode ser traduzido em vários idiomas. Para cada idioma ira existir um registro de conteúdo. A ideia de ter o artigo como entidade pai foi que os comentários e avaliações serão do artigo, independente do idioma que ele esteja

Comment: Você está usando `ApiController` pra salvar o código?

Comment: Olá @CiganoMorrisonMendez, deixei esse projeto de lado por enquanto, mas estava utilizando sim o ApiController para salvar. Pretendo retomá-lo em no máximo 15 dias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A decisão de um ou dois POST vai depender quase sempre do negócio.

Pelo que entendi, no seu caso creio que o melhor seria dois POST separados, permitindo que artigo seja complementado com um novo idioma no futuro.

Sobre o problema de não ter um filho salvo, recomendo que o cliente que usar essa WebAPI verifique cada filho se a requisição foi feita com sucesso, senão tentar uma segunda vez ou alertar o usuário para ele decidir se deve ou não tentar novamente salvar aquele idioma específico. Isso pode ser feito apenas verificando o código HTTP de retorno.